# C++ Stuck in switching through my game's areas

Tags: c++, loops

Hello people and I'm learning how to make text-based RPG games and I've encountered an error. So first here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void newGameFunc();
void titleFunc();
int userInput = 0;
int playerInfo[2];
int playerLocation = 0;


bool running = 1;

int main() {
    while (running) {
        titleFunc();
        if (playerLocation == 1) {
            cout << "You are standing in the middle of a forest. A path veers off to the East and to the West.\n";
            cout << " 1: Go East\n 2: Go West\n";
            cin >> userInput;

            if (userInput == 1) playerLocation = 2; //East
            else if (userInput == 2) playerLocation = 3; //West 
        }
        if (playerLocation == 2) {
            cout << "You are in the Eastern edge of the forest. It's heavilly forested and it's almost imposible to navigate through. You do find 2 flags though.\n";
            cout << " 1: Turn Back\n 2: Pick the FLAG.\n";
            cin >> userInput;

            if (userInput == 1) playerLocation = 1; //Start
            if (userInput == 2) running = 0;
        }
        if (playerLocation == 3) {
            cout << "There is a passage way that leads to a town in the seemingly distant town. There are two guards with shining metal chainmail which scales look as magistic as reptilian scales. Their logo resembles a black dragon spewing a string of fire. They tell you that in order to pass you must give them their lost flags.\n";
            cout << " 1: Give the flags to both guards.\n 2: Turn around.\n 3: Bribe them--NOT AVAILABLE.)\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void titleFunc() {
    cout << "\t\t\t\t---Fantasee---\n\n\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t   1: Play\n";
    cin >> userInput;

    if (userInput == 1) {
        newGameFunc();
    }
    else {
        running = 0;
    }
    return;
}

void newGameFunc() {
    cout << "Welcome to Fantasee, a world of adventure and danger.\n";
    cout << "Since you are a new hero, why don't you tell me a little about yourself?\n";
    cout << "For starters, are you a boy or a girl?\n 1: Boy\n 2: Girl\n";
    cin >> userInput;
    playerInfo[0] = userInput;

    cout << "And what kind of person are you?\n 1: Warrior\n 2: Archer\n 3: All-rounder\n";
    cin >> userInput;
    playerInfo[1] = userInput;
    playerLocation = 1;
    system("cls");
    return;
}
```

So the problem is that let's say when I go the `playerLocation 2` and I want to go back to `playerLocation 1` it will just start the function `titleFunc();` not the `if (playerLocation == 1)` statement.

Comment: You should explain when should `titleFunc()` be invoked.

Comment: @SJuan76 So how do I make it so that it explains that it should only be ran once? When the game is first loaded.

Comment: Put it **outside** the loop (the `while` statement).

Comment: @SJuan76 Aha that's the problem. How could I not notice that.

Comment: I can give an answer to that too, but probably it would get deleted.... just kidding, of course. :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably want to put the `titleFunc()` before the while loop:

```
int main() {
    while (running) {
        titleFunc();
        ...
```

into:

```
int main() {
    titleFunc();
    while (running) {
        ...
```

the way you are doing it right now you keep running `titleFunc()` in every iteration of the loop and reset the game with it.